# How can we get CSS @container queries to consider the viewport to be the root container?

Tags: css, container-queries

Container queries seem like such a great addition to CSS, one that I've been looking forward to for years. But having just started using them, I've run into this issue.

`@container` queries do not fall back to the viewport container size if the element doesn't have a container. The obvious thing to do then is to just put `container: root / inline-size;` on the `html` tag, but that changes the behaviour of `position: fixed` elements on the page (they become relative to the html tag's size, not to the viewport).

I've put together a minimal repro here that also explains the issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-jackson-p5gp80?file=/index.html

One idea I've had is a pattern where you use min-width media queries and then max-width container queries. So if an element is not in a container it gets the styles from the largest matching min-width media query size, but if it *is* in a container, the media-query styles get overridden by container query styles. This seems like it would work, but would also result in a lot of duplicate CSS rules.

Another pattern is to try to put more container rules around the place, but I've already run into issues using this pattern, with `position: fixed;` elements misbehaving when inside a container.

Perhaps a third pattern I haven't tried is to add a single containing div inside the body with the height and width of the viewport, and `overflow: auto;`. And make *that* the root container.

It would be so much simpler if container queries just considered the viewport to be the outer-most container, or if there was a way to opt-in to this behaviour. Has anyone dealt with this already, or have any ideas for better patterns?